# Command to opt-out of greetings from Discord.JS bot using presenceUpdate listener

Tags: discord.js

I have a Discord.js bot that is programmed to send a greeting message whenever a user's status becomes online. Some users don't like this feature, and rather than removing the feature, I am making a command to opt out of it.

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let member = newPresence.member;
    Object.assign(member, {"ignoreStatuses": false})
    console.log(member)
    let guild = newPresence.guild;
    const newGame = newPresence.member.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type)
    console.log(newGame)
    let channelId = "884295684814151680"
    let greetChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId)
});
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`!greetings`)) {
        var args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
        if (args === "on") {
            member.ignoreStatuses = false
        };
        if (args === "off") {
            member.ignoreStatuses = true
        };
    }
});
```

The problem is, whenever a user does !greetings on/off, the program throws an error saying `member` is not defined. Member is defined in the presenceUpdate listener, though. I'm sure that the problem is because they are two different listeners and the object doesn't quite carry over between them. Does anyone know any clever solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup! Your insight  on your problem is absolutely correct, the variable member isn't reachable since it's a parameter of your `presenceUpdate` listener while you're trying to use it in your `message` event listener, you can simply overcome this via defining it outside of **either** of those and reassigning its value everytime you're using it like so:

```js
let member;
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    member = newPresence.member;
    if(member.ignoreStatuses) {
    let guild = newPresence.guild;
    const newGame = newPresence.member.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type)
    console.log(newGame)
    let channelId = "884295684814151680"
    let greetChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId)
}
});
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`!greetings`)) {
        var args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
        if (args === "on") {
            member.ignoreStatuses = false
        };
        if (args === "off") {
            member.ignoreStatuses = true
        };
    }
});
```